# Tomcat DataSource - Max Active Connections

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, connection-pooling, tomcat-jdbc

I set max active connections to 1 using the below code :

```
    ConnectionPool initializePool(DataSource dataSource) {
    if (!(org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource.class.isInstance(dataSource))) {
        return null;
    }
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource tomcatDataSource = (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) dataSource;
    final String poolName = tomcatDataSource.getName();
    try {
        ConnectionPool pool = tomcatDataSource.createPool();
        pool.getPoolProperties().setMaxActive(1);
        pool.getPoolProperties().setInitialSize(1);
        pool.getPoolProperties().setTestOnBorrow(true);
        return pool;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.info(String.format(" !--! creation of pool failed for %s", poolName), e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now using threads , I have opened number of concurrent connections to DB. I also printed out the current active number of connections using the below listed code

```
System.out.println("Current Active Connections = " + ((org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) datasource).getActive());
System.out.println("Max Active Connections = " + ((org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) datasource).getMaxActive());
```

I see results similar to below. Active connections is being displayed as more than 1. However I want to restrict the max active connections to 1. Are there any other parameters that I need to set?

> Current Active Connections = 9
>
> Max Active Connections = 1

EDIT: However when I try with 15 or 20 as max active , it is always limited to 15 or 20 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Try with maxIdle and minIdle

```
ConnectionPool pool = tomcatDataSource.createPool();
pool.getPoolProperties().setMaxActive(1);
pool.getPoolProperties().setInitialSize(1);
pool.getPoolProperties().setMaxIdle(1);
pool.getPoolProperties().setMinIdle(1);
pool.getPoolProperties().setTestOnBorrow(true);
```